# Update Active Directory for domain admins

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I've built an application (asp.net 2010) to allow our employees to update some of their information in Active Directory. Data like website, degree, campus, building, phone extension, etc.

Everything works fine until a user who is a domain admin attempts to use the app.  Since the "service account" my .Net application is using is not a domain admin, the update fails for them.

Is there a way I can make this happen without having to make my "service account" a domain admin?

Answer (score 0):

You could give your service account permission to the Domain Adminis object in AD (Read Write).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Correct, but I was wondering if there was a different alternative.